# Restore history to split repository

Tags: mercurial, split, repository

Rightly or wrongly (almost certainly wrongly) I've ended up in the following position:

We used to have one big mercurial repository.  We have now moved a large portion of this code base in to a separate repository. Looking back, it seems we could have done this in such a way that kept the file history, but naively we simply copied the files in to the new repository.

We are now in a position where the two repositories have been split, but I want to attach the file history of the moved files to those in the new repository.  The files have been deleted in the original repository - but this history obviously still exists.

Is there anyway to "pre-pend" the history of the files in the original repository to those in the split repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) allows you to convert a Mercurial repository to another one while excluding and modifying filenames (using the `--filemap` option).

So use the convert command twice, one for each split, and use a corresponding filemap which only involves the files supposed to be in the particular target repository.

**If you already did commits in the split repos you do not want to loose**, use the convert approach anyway and afterwards migrate your new commits made in the splits w/o history to your new split repos made with convert:

Suppose your old splits with lost history are `os1` and `os2` and your new splits made with the convert command are `ns1` and `ns2`. Then in `ns1` you would do

1. `hg pull --force os1` (force is required because you pull from an unrelated repo),
2. `hg rebase -s <first-new-commit-made-in-os1> -d <last-converted-commit-in-ns1>` (rebase new commits onto your split made with convert)
3. `hg strip <first-commit-at-all-in-os1>` ([discard](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension) everything you pulled from `os1` but not needed anymore)

Do it similarly with `os2` and `ns2`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about attaching the file history after you've already done the split, but if you can do it all over again this is one option:

In your original repository, go back to the last revision (REV) before you deleted the files:

```
hg up -r REV
```

Go up one level from the original repository and make two new clones:

```
hg clone OriginalRepo Split1
hg clone OriginalRepo Split2
```

Go into *Split1*, delete the files you don't want in that repository, and commit. Do the same for *Split2*. These two are now your new split repositories, both with a complete history. Of course, the history for all deleted files (even those you initially didn't want in the repository) will exist equally in both repositories as well.

If you've done a lot of work in your new repositories *after* you made the split, you might be able to add these to your *Split1* and *Split2* by using export/import (check `hg help import` and `hg help export`). Depending on the number of changes you've made, there might be better ways to do this (e.g. *mercurial queues*), but this is what came to my mind first.